# Infinite LOOP/Repeat script?

Tags: vb.net, loops, browser, refresh

I have a script in Visual Basic that I can't seem to get it to repeat/loop. I want the script to repeat after having click for the variable given, and then the page refresh. Then the page refreshes and the ticks is at 0, but then I want the script to repeat all over again (INFINITE). Here is the script i'm dealing with:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  If Not number_of_ticks > 100 Then
    number_of_ticks += 1
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
  Else
    'number_of_ticks has exceed the maximum amount of allowed ticks
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
    number_of_ticks = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

but when I try to do a LOOP, it doesn't work, the program becomes unresponsive:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  Do
    If Not number_of_ticks > 100 Then
      number_of_ticks += 1
      WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
    Else
      'number_of_ticks has exceed the maximum amount of allowed ticks
      Timer1.Enabled = False
      WebBrowser1.Refresh()
      number_of_ticks = 0
    End If
  Loop
End Sub
```

I don't know why this is happening, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Do-Loop` causes the program to be stuck forever.  Maybe you should just re-enable the timer in your method:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Not number_of_ticks > 100 And Not WebBrowser1.IsBusy Then
        number_of_ticks += 1
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
    Else
        'number_of_ticks has exceed the maximum amount of allowed ticks
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()
        number_of_ticks = 0

        ' re-enable the timer to repeat again
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh, I thought this would've worked but there's a problem: http://gyazo.com/2a6935adecafffe3f4628fe899c7cd28 and what I think this problem means is it is trying to go back to clicking before the page is fully refreshed. So I think I need to put an IF WebBrowser is Loaded THEN enable Timer1, but I am fairly new at VB and I was wondering how would I put an IF in  IF statement?

Comment: @JackC. - I haven't done a lot with the browser control, so my edit may not work for you. The `IsBusy` flag tells you if the browser is still loading a file, and might be something to use here as a check. I added the check for `IsBusy` in the first `If` statement.